# call api function using curl in php

Tags: php

I have a simple Rest Based API function how can i call this function by send value as a parameter

this is the code

```
public function CheckIfUserExist($id)
{
    $sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `".APICONFIG::DB."`.`".CLIENTINFO::TABLE_CLIENT."` 
                        WHERE ".
                        CLIENTINFO::CLIENT_ID." = '".$id."'",
                         $this->db);
    $num_rows = mysql_num_rows($sql);

    if($num_rows > 0 )
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}
```

this is what i am trying

```
$url = $domain.'db/register/RegisterUserAPI/CheckIfUserExist';            
$ch = curl_init($url);        
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

$response = curl_exec($ch);
$httpCode = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
curl_close($ch);
```

how can i call this function and send a value as a parameter

Comment: You can't call functions over HTTP. You have to make a request to a URL, and then have server side code determine what functions to call based on that.

Comment: please give me any example in which a parametrized function is called using curl

Answer (score 1, accepted):

put your function in a file and call it by receiving parameter

**call_fun.php**

```
if(isset($_REQUEST['id']))
{
   $id = $_REQUEST['id'];
   if(CheckIfUserExist($id))
   { 
      echo "Exists";
   }
   else
   {
        echo "Not Exists";
   }
}

public function CheckIfUserExist($id)
{
    $sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `".APICONFIG::DB."`.`".CLIENTINFO::TABLE_CLIENT."` 
                        WHERE ".
                        CLIENTINFO::CLIENT_ID." = '".$id."'",
                         $this->db);
    $num_rows = mysql_num_rows($sql);

    if($num_rows > 0 )
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}
```

Now in Curl pass parameter like

```
$url = $domain.'db/register/RegisterUserAPI/CheckIfUserExist/call_fun.php'; // path to your php file call_fun.php
$id="123"; // you can set it  

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,  $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "id=$id");
$buffer = curl_exec($ch);
echo $buffer;
curl_close($ch);
```